# node project in typescript : free memory

Tags: node.js, typescript, memory-management

I am developping a node project in typescript, as I am totally new to the node/ecmascript/typescript ecosystem, I was having a question and I am not able to test and confirm my idea :

If I have an object with multiple properties (2 array properties in my example), that are taking a lot of memory space, how can I free them once I am done with them. These are the possible soltions coming to my mind :

```
myObj = null

or

myObj = undefined

or

myObj.prop1 = null
myObj.prop2 = null

or

myObj.prop1 = undefined
myObj.prop2 = undefined
```

So basically I am wondering :

1. if cleaning each property of the object is the same as cleaning the object in one single time
2. if cleaning with null is the same as cleaning with undefined to indicate to the garbage collector that this object can be removed

This is my tsconfig if needed :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}
```

I am using node v12.16.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete them and let garbage collection sort it out:

```
delete myObj.prop1;
```

In general though if you have data you need to do something with, but dont want to keep it in memory, just fetch it and use it in the same closure, so when that closure is returned everything gets cleaned up. Eg:

```
function doSomethingWithBigArray() {
  const bigArray = getBigArray();
  // do something with it.
}
doSomethingWithBigArray();
```

That way once you've done whatever you need to do the closure is gone and you don't have that big chunk of data in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so with you first solution, I will always have to iterate on every property, I can't clean the whole object in one single time?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have an object with multiple properties (2 array properties in my example), that are taking a lot of memory space, how can I free them once I am done with them.

You don't need to clean up after yourself. JavaScript engines has a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) that do that for you. E.g. V8 has a garbage collector named [Orinoco](https://v8.dev/blog/trash-talk). Since, Node.js uses JavaScript engine V8 under the hood, it means that garbage collector Orinoco is applied.

Moreover, using `delete` operator can harm your performance (or not, it depends on your scenario and JavaScript engine).

So, I can advice you to not use `delete` operators or trying to cleanup after yourself. Just use everything like you want to and in most cases garbage collector will do anything else.

```
function doSomethingWithMyObject() {
  myObj.prop1 = ['a', 'huge', 'array', 'here']
  myObj.prop2 = ['a', 'huge', 'array', 'here'];

  // doing some heavy stuff here with them

  // function is done and you return something useful
  return usefulData;
}

// myObj will be cleared after that, or, at least, marked for cleaning by GC
```

**UPD: Does it make sense to help GC clear the memory in JavaScript?**

In my opinion, it does not. Orinoco uses Mark & Sweep technique (although, strongly optimized and modified) and keeps track of everything that points to each other.

The only thing you can do to help GC clean the memory - is avoid dangling references to objects. Once the JavaScript object loses all the accessible references to it, GC will clean it.

**UPD2: Does `delete` operator helps in cleaning memory?**

No. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description):

> Unlike what common belief suggests, the delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory. Memory management is done indirectly via breaking references.

Is there a way to indicate "something to clean" in JavaScript? No.

Comment: Reading the question, I think that OP is well-aware that Node has GC and how GC work in general - he's not asking how to free memory as in C, he's asking about how to properly indicate to GC that it should be cleared.

Comment: There is no sense in doing that (indicating that something can be cleared). I'll update the answer for that.

Comment: First of all, it might make sense in some contexts. But most importantly, OP's not asking about whether it's good practice or not, he's asking about how can he achieve that. Even if it something is a bad practice, figuring out how to do that bad practice is still valuable from educational perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but even with your updated answer : if I do not set any reference to null or undefined to an object that I have created before, this will still exist in memory and will take memory space if I don't do anything and if I stay in the same closure?

Comment: Yes, your objects will be in memory till the last reference to them. In case, all your objects are created in closure and you do not pass reference to them in other closures - they will be cleaned from memory when you exit the closure.

Comment: ok thanks, but if I have a object in my "global" closure, not inside any method, I will keep this data during all my program execution, would not be a good idea to set it to null (or undefined) to avoid wasting memory ?

Comment: Please, read again my answer and references I've provided. Setting `null` or `undefined` or anything to variables in JavaScript has nothing to do with freeing memory

Comment: You can free memory by getting rid of references to your data, period